# ¿Cómo verificar el número de elementos en una fila específica de una matriz? - Python

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Python, que básicamente es un juego de estrategia, el mismo que debe finalizar cuando lleguen al menos 5 elementos a la primera fila de la matriz (campobatalla), no sé cómo formular la pregunta de mejor manera. :(

```
    print(r"*****Bienvenido a strategy 14.10.85*****")
    import random as rnd
    import numpy as np
    validacion1=False
    while validacion1==False:
       dimcampobatalla = input("ingrese la dimension del campo de 
          batalla,\nrecuerde que la dimension debe ser entre 10 y 20: ")
if dimcampobatalla.isdigit()==False or int(dimcampobatalla)<10 or int(dimcampobatalla)>20:  #preguntar para validar que no se ingrese simbolos, se cae el programa
    print("Por favor ingrese únicamente números entre 10 y 20",sep="\n")
else:
    validacion1=True
dimnum = int(dimcampobatalla)
print("la dimension ingresada es: ", dimnum)

campobatalla=(np.zeros((dimnum, dimnum),int))
campobatalla[dimnum-1]=[(np.random.randint(0,5))for j in range (dimnum)]
cruz=np.array([[0,-1,0],[-1,-1,-1],[0,-1,-0]])
latigo=np.array([[0,-2,0],[0,-3,-0],[0,-2,-0]])
estrella=np.array([[-1,-3,-1],[-2,-1,-2],[-1,-3,-1]])
print(campobatalla)
subir = np.vstack((campobatalla,campobatalla[dimnum-1]))
```

En esta parte tengo dudas, no sé como aplicar el vstack sin perder el progreso actual, he llamado a esto "subir"

```
     validacion2=False
     while validacion2==False:
     ataquezonafila = input("el numero maximo de fila debera ser la dimension reducida en tres: ")
     if ataquezonafila.isdigit()==False or int(ataquezonafila) not in range (0,dimnum-2):
       print("el numero de fila es invalido",sep="\n")
     else:
       validacion2=True
      fila=int(ataquezonafila)

   validacion3 = False
   while validacion3 == False:
   ataquezonacolumna = input("el numero maximo de columna debera ser la dimension reducida en tres: ")
   if ataquezonacolumna.isdigit()==False or int(ataquezonacolumna) not in range(0,dimnum-2):
       print("el numero de columna es invalido", sep="\n")
   else:
       validacion3 = True
   columna=int(ataquezonacolumna)

   validacion4 = False
    while validacion4 == False:
    tipoimpacto=input("Por favor escoja el tipo de ataque: 1=Cruz, 2=Látigo, 3=Estrella")
    if tipoimpacto.isdigit()==False or int(tipoimpacto) not in range (0,4):
       print("Número inválido.")
    else:
       validacion4 = True
    tipo=int(tipoimpacto)

    print("coordenada 2 columna: ",columna)
    print("el ataque sera dirigido a coordenadas [",fila,"]:[",columna,"]")
    zonaimpacto=(campobatalla[fila:fila+3,columna:columna+3])
    print(zonaimpacto)
```

Creé listas para contar cuántas veces se usó cada tipo de ataque

```
    at1=[]
    at2=[]
    at3=[]

    if tipo==1:
       impacto=campobatalla[fila,columna]-(cruz)
       print(impacto)
       at1.append(impacto)
    elif tipo==2:
       impacto = campobatalla[fila, columna] - (latigo)
       print(impacto)
       at2.append(impacto)
    else:
       impacto = campobatalla[fila, columna] - (estrella)
       print(impacto)
       at3.append(impacto)

    a = 0
    for i in range(fila,fila+3):
        b = 0

        for j in range(columna,columna + 3):
          campobatalla[i,j] = impacto[a,b]
          b = b + 1

    a = a + 1

    print(campobatalla)
```

Comment: Hola Jhoss, bienvenido a [es.so]. Intenta siempre crear un ejemplo [mcve], colocar mucho código sin ir al grano del problema dificulta la tarea de la gente dispuesta a ayudar. En todo caso, aunque publique un código extenso haz que sea reproducible al menos, tu código tiene graves problemas de identación y eso en Python es crucial. Dicho esto, ¿Que pretendes exactamente conseguir con `vstack`? Ahora simplemente obtienes el contenido de `campobatalla` duplicando la última fila. Intenta explicar un poco mejor el problema y la reproducibilidad del código a ver si te podemos ayudar. Un saludo.

Comment: te recomiendo escoger las palabras adecuadas cuando realices una explicación, porque hasta ahora no entiendo la siguiente frase: *debe finalizar cuando lleguen al menos 5 elementos a la primera fila de la matriz*. :P